# String from\to GregorianCalendar cause java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, android, gregorian-calendar, parseexception

I need to convert a `GregorianCalendar` to  a `String` and reconvert this string to a `GregorianCalendar` again

I use this to convert the `String` in a `GregorianCalendar`

```
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = format.parse(dateS);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(date);
```

Unfortunately when I invoke the second method I get this error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11 apr 2014 21:48:02" (at offset 2)
```

at this line

```
date = format.parse(dateS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your `SimpleDateFormat` object with the pattern it will use to parse the date String. In your case:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

A table of the acceptable pattern symbols can be found in the  [docs for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)